# Select From a table limiting by column of another table

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I have a table named **question_dispositions** composed like this

```
Type | chapter | number
-------------------------
 A   |    1    |    3
 B   |    1    |    2
 B   |    4    |    1
```

The second table named **question** has columns type, text and chapter.

```
Type | chapter | text
-----------------------
 A   |    1    |    T1
 A   |    1    |    T2
 B   |    1    |    T3 
 B   |    1    |    T4 
 B   |    1    |    T5 
 B   |    2    |    T6 
 B   |    2    |    T7 
 B   |    3    |    T8
 B   |    4    |    T9
```

What I need is to fetch X random questions from table **Question** where the X is the column *number* from **question_dispositions**

So if I need questions of type B the result that I expect is this:

```
 chapter | text
 --------------
    1    |  T3 
    1    |  T4
    4    |  T9
```

How can I Select random question limiting by the column number in another table? I tried with this query but returns every row in the table Question as expected because I can not limit with qd.count

```
SELECT * FROM 
question_dispositions AS qd, question AS q 
 WHERE qd.chapter = q.chapter AND qd.type = q.type AND qd.type = 'B'
```

Comment: T5 should also be there ?

Comment: Show your query which you tried ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar No because I need just 2 questions from the chapter 1.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Updated with the actual query :)

Comment: You could include a new derived column of type GUID....
(SELECT UUID()) in a sub select.

Then select from that and order by that new derived column and take the top X rows using LIMIT.
I'd imagine that would be pretty random.

Comment: @AntDC Could you explain me better with an example? Thanks

Comment: So you want X number of questions. [You'll have to look up how to use a field value for this]
I mainly use SQL server so untested but I think it can't be far off.  Just trying to help.
Good luck

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT *,  (SELECT UUID()) as myRand  FROM 
question_dispositions AS qd, question AS q 
 WHERE qd.chapter = q.chapter AND qd.type = q.type AND qd.type = 'B'
)
ORDER BY myRand
LIMIT X

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY RAND() is a typical approach to randomness in MySQL but it is usually criticized because it does not scale well. Here however you appear to be selecting a quite small number of rows as questions but to achieve some randomness of those. So, here is an approach using ORDER BY RAND() which should be acceptable in performance for small result sets.

There is an added requirement to LIMIT by a stored `Number`, however in the small example supplied that number isn't consistent for type B so I chose to limit by the maximum of that number for the wanted type B. MySQL doesn't allow use of variables or subqueries with the LIMIT clause so instead a generated row number is used in a where clause to achieve that outcome.

Refer to this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5246e/1)

**Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE question_dispositions 
    (`Type` varchar(1), `chapter` int, `number` int)
;

INSERT INTO question_dispositions 
    (`Type`, `chapter`, `number`)
VALUES
    ('A', 1, 3),
    ('B', 1, 2),
    ('B', 4, 1)
;

CREATE TABLE question
    (`Type` varchar(1), `chapter` int, `text` varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO question
    (`Type`, `chapter`, `text`)
VALUES
    ('A', 1, 'T1'),
    ('A', 1, 'T2'),
    ('B', 1, 'T3'),
    ('B', 1, 'T4'),
    ('B', 1, 'T5'),
    ('B', 2, 'T6'),
    ('B', 2, 'T7'),
    ('B', 3, 'T8'),
    ('B', 4, 'T9')
;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rn , q.* 
    FROM question_dispositions AS qd
    INNER JOIN question AS q ON qd.chapter = q.chapter AND qd.type = q.type 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    WHERE qd.type = 'B'
    ORDER BY RAND()
    ) d
WHERE rn <= (SELECT MAX(NUMBER) FROM question_dispositions WHERE type = 'B')
```

**[Example Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5246e/1/0)**:

```
| rn | Type | chapter | text |
|----|------|---------|------|
|  1 |    B |       1 |   T3 |
|  2 |    B |       1 |   T4 |
```